# Include an external JS library In Angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

My goal is to use an external JavaScript Library in an Angular 2 project. To do so, there are two ways:

1) Declare those variables in my files (they will be present in the environment during runtime) like this:

```
declare var numbro: any; // in my Component
```

And I added the numbro.js file like this in the index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>APP Angular 2</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="../node_modules/numbro/numbro.js"></script>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

2) The other solution is to use their declaration files in TypeScript (if they already exist)

The problem here is that not all JavaScript libraries support TypeScript and it didn't seem a good idea to create declaration files for each library I want to use in my project. Therefore, I decided to adopt the first way. Everything seemed good until I faced this error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: require is not defined

Here is my webpack configuration:

```js
'use strict';

const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const communConfig = require('./webpack-commun.config.js');

module.exports = function(options) {
  const hotModuleReplacementPlugin = new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin();
  const commonsChunkPlugin = new CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: [ 'vendor', 'polyfills' ]
  });
  const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: options.html
  });

  return merge(communConfig(options), {
    entry: {
      polyfills: options.polyfills,
      vendor: options.vendor,
      app: [
        `webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:${options.port}`,
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        options.entry
      ]
    },

    output: {
      path: options.outputDir,
      publicPath: `http://localhost:${options.port}`,
      filename: '[name].js',
      chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    plugins: [
      hotModuleReplacementPlugin,
      commonsChunkPlugin,
      htmlPlugin
    ]
  });
};
```

Here is my vendor.ts file:

```js
import 'rxjs';
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/compiler';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import 'numbro';
```

And Here is my pollyfills.ts:

```js
import 'es6-shim';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'ts-helpers';
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Do you use system.js in your project?

Comment: What version of angular 2 are  you using? You can find that in package.json file. - for example mine says: "@angular/common": "2.0.0", . So is 2.0 final release - no RC candidates here. If you are using the angular CLI please mention because is a hole other answer. At first glance you don't have webpack setup but i can't help you without more info.

Comment: @galvan No i didn't use system.js in my project

Comment: @AIon Yes i work with the final release 2.0 , I didn't use angular CLI

Comment: @AIon I added the webpack file can you please have a look :) Thanks